# Entity Framework Many to One Relationship with POCO generating FK in second entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following POCO relationship;

```
public class Equipment : Entity
{
    //... removed for brevity
    public virtual List<Qualification> RequiredQualifications { get; set; }
}

    public class Qualification : AuditableEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //... removed for brevity
}
```

So its a one way relationship where the same `Qualification` can be linked to the `Equipment`.

Entity Framework 6 creates the FK EquipmentId in the generate Qualifications table, which then breaks the fact the same qualification can be linked multiple equipment.

Do I need to create a linking POCO or can I set this up (through FluentAPI) to automatically generate the link between the two eneities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a piece of Equipment can have multiple Qualifications, and a Qualification can be linked to multiple pieces of Equipment, you need to configure a many-to-many relationship.

The easiest way to do this is to configure Navigation Properties on both entities:

```
public class Equipment : Entity
{
    //... removed for brevity
    public virtual ICollection<Qualification> RequiredQualifications { get; } = new HashSet<Qualification>();
}

public class Qualification : AuditableEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Equipment> RelatedEquipment { get; } = new HashSet<Equipment>();
    //... removed for brevity
}
```

Or if you don't want a Navigation property from Qualification to Equipment then use the FluentAPI to configure this as a Many-to-Many relationship.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Equipment>().HasMany(e => e.RequiredQualifications).WithMany();

}
```